# Get size of multiple folders - How to calculate server resources consumption of the process?

Tags: debian, php, resources

I need to get the size of multiple folders (with subfolders and several files) and update a database, in order to limit the users upload to my server. This process must be done periodically, in the shortest time possible.

I created a crontab to execute this procedure each 30 minutes, but would be great if this time interval could be reduced to 10 minutes or less. I have no idea how much resources this process is taking from server. I have a humble VPS with 1 GB RAM, 1 CPU, Debian 8, Apache2 and MariaDB.

My question is: how to calculate server resources consumption of this process, in order to estimate which time interval to use?

Btw, here is the PHP function I am using to get folder (and subfolders) size:

```
function dirSize($dir) {
    $dir = strval($dir);
    if (!is_dir($dir)) return 0;
    $cmd = popen("ls -ltrR {$dir} |awk '{print \$5}'|awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum=sum+\$1} END {print sum}'", 'r');
    $size = intval(fgets($cmd, 80));
    pclose($cmd);
    return $size;
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I received a good suggestion from **@meuh** to update the database each time a file is uploaded or deleted, adding or subtracting the single file size. I'd like to know, in terms of resources consumption, if this is a better approach. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to manually observe resource usage most people start with `top`.

Comment: It would make more sense to calculate this only for a given user when they were actually trying to upload a file.

Comment: @BLayer, I am preparing the server to start activities, today we have only few test directories and files. But I will try to add more files and use `htop`. Do you think it is fast enough to show resources changes when testing the process with, let's say, 10 folders and 10,000 files?

Comment: @meuh, files will be uploaded at all time, by multiple users at same time. So I do not think it is a good idea to calculate the folder size everytime a new file is uploaded...

Comment: If your php code is the only thing allowing new files to be created, then clearly you should simply keep in your database a count of how many bytes each user has used so far, and update it every time they upload a new file. Adding a number to an entry in a database is much better than doing a `du`, as this will make your disk cache unable to hold anything useful except all the directories that `du` keeps reading.

Comment: Fair points @meuh but given that this is apparently running on a single, low-powered server I'm not envisioning an enterprise-class service with millions of users...a relatively "low-tech" approach could be a good place to start. But giving OP different options is a good thing.

Comment: @meuh, it is indeed a good idea! With your knownledge and experience, do you think updating a MySQL database everytime a file is uploaded/deleted is a better approach than getting the directory size every 10 minutes or so using `du`? I mean, comparing server resources consumption of course...

Comment: The `du` will always be the worst solution. Keeping your own count of space used will probably always be the best, but it does require you to write more code. There is a third way: get the system to do the counting for you. Check up on [disk quotas](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html). In this case you ask the filesystem to count how much data each user uses, and when that user tries to create files using more space, they fail. In this case  you must create a real userid for each person, though.

Comment: I do not mind write more code, I am searching for efficiency here. About the third way, would be the best approach if each user had a real user id, but unfortunately it is not the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `du` command:

> du - estimate file space usage

Example:

```
$ du -d 0 -h Documents/
3.2M    Documents/
```

The `du` command has lots of options, you could even pass it all the directories at once and get a total of the disk usage (check `man du` for more info).

To find the time taken (in a practical way), you could prepend `time` to it:

```
$ time du -d 0 -h Documents/
3.2M    Documents/

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.001s
```

This time likely varies with the amount of files and folders in a directory.

Comment: Hi Aaditya! Ok, `du` seems to be much faster than `ls` used in current function. But my question is about resources consumption. Do you think I can use `du` each 10 minutes to get the size from maybe 10,000 directories, each one with up to 10 subdirectories and hundreds of files, without heavely impact in the server resources? Thank you!

Comment: I find that `du -s` is pretty fast even with large file trees. Note that the tool description says " _estimate_ file space usage". I think it's fairly well optimized.

Comment: @BLayer, "estimate" size is enough for me. I will do a research about `du` to understand how it works. Maybe it gets the size from some directories pre-calculated information table, generated by Linux. Thanks!